Second HDD not showing up after Ubuntu Server reboot
Probably a NOOB question but after install of Ubuntu Server 24.04 and a secondary internal SSD (sda1) is mounted, partitioned, file system created and appears as /mnt/sandisk, it appears as unmounted after a reboot. Prior to reboot I can make directories and move files with no problems. What am I doing wrong? Do  I need to edit some config file or create a script,or ?

To ensure your secondary HDD (sda1) mounts automatically after a reboot, you need to add it to the /etc/fstab file. Here’s how you can do it:
Find the UUID of the Disk:
Open a terminal.
Run sudo blkid to find the UUID of sda1.
Edit the /etc/fstab File:
Open the fstab file with a text editor:
sudo nano /etc/fstab
Add a new line with the UUID and mount point. It should look something like this:
UUID=your-uuid-here /mnt/sandisk ext4 defaults 0 2
Replace your-uuid-here with the actual UUID of sda1 and ext4 with the appropriate file system type if it's different.
Test the fstab Configuration:
Run sudo mount -a to test if the fstab entry is correct. If there are no errors, the configuration is correct.
Reboot and Verify:
Reboot your system to ensure the changes take effect.
After rebooting, verify that the disk is mounted with df -h or ls /mnt/sandisk.

Worked perfectly! Thank you, Danut!

I would like to know how to resolve the issue when an error occurs.
See attachment, as this occurs after each reboot. When I do the mount -a option all seems to work, however the error keeps popping up. I must be doing something wrong here. It is unclear to me if there are drives not showing up.


This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
